# What does "static" in brackets in function parameters mean?

Tags: c, parameters, static, function-parameter

I saw a function whose prototype was this:

```
int foo(int arr[static], size_t len);
```

I have learnt that it's possible to put `const` and `volatile` there, which should be adjusted to pointers pointing to objects with corresponding cv-qualifiers. But this time it doesn't seem quite the same as

```
int foo(static int *arr, size_t len);
```

as `static` shouldn't appear here at all.

So what is it at last?